# Fetching user profile from my firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

Is there any way i could fetch my user profile from my firebase account?

Like I logged in my firebase account using my gmail id, did authentication and store data in database now I want to show the username after being logged in into my project.

Any tutorials or videos?

Sorry for asking a little weird question but i did not found out any appropriate place to learn

Comment: Checkout this: https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth or this https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ both pages are from the same author the fireship.io is new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
     if (!user) {
       this.displayName = null;        
       return;
     }
     this.displayName = user.displayName;      
   });
}
```